# Redirect not works correctly

Tags: .htaccess

This simple rule should redirect to url without one word (picture-display):

```
RewriteRule en/catalog/picture-display/(.*)$ en/catalog/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

But it redirect from **[www.example.com/en/catalog/picture-display/something](http://www.example.com/en/catalog/picture-display/something)** to **[www.example.com/en](http://www.example.com/en)**. What I am doing bad?

Before this rule I have this. Would not influence it?

```
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

**EDIT**

**Whole .htaccess:**
path/.htaccess

```
Header unset ETag
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess/?$ - [NC,F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /public/$1

RewriteRule ^(cs/katalog)/obrazkove-zobrazeni/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/picture-display/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

**htaccess to route from documentRoute:**

path/public/.htaccess (document route) - there is index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

**Result of cmd**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try following htaccess rules in your file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Header unset ETag
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /public/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^public /public/index.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess/?$ - [NC,F]


RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/picture-display/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(cs/katalog)/obrazkove-zobrazeni/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Keep your path/public/.htaccess (document route) like as follows:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly nothing happened. I have cleared cache memory and tested on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=aa25efa9-c8f4-4b87-83c5-9b1b857fdde1. There is correct, but not in my website, even on localhost. What it could cause?

Comment: @tomasr, Request you not to test htaccess rules on Online sites, they don't work properly IMHO. Please do let me know which sample url you are hitting and what is the error you have seen?

Comment: Whatever I tested on apache (remote and local), it did not redirect to anywhere. For example https://www.example.com/en/catalog/picture-display/europa/great-britain will stay on the same url. So I do not see any error.

Comment: @tomasr, could you please do confirm once if you have cleared cache from your browser and then tested these?

Comment: Yes I have cleared of browser cache and I tested in firefox and chrome. I inserted whole htaccess to edited question. Maybe there is some problem with rules which I do not send before.

Comment: @tomasr, could you please do let me know if you have other rules too in your htaccess file? If yes then please update then in your question and let me know then.

Comment: @tomasr, could you please try my edited rules once? Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: @tomasr, `htaccess to route from documentRoute:` is it a 2nd htaccess file in your system? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on an explanation. Your new htaccess does nothing (with the cache cleared). I found that there is another htaccess that I can't delete because it points from the document route to index.php in another folder. I don't know there can't be a conflict with your file.

Comment: @tomasr, ok could you please post sample of paths of both of htaccess files? Where they are present in system.

Comment: I have changed in my question. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @tomasr, no problem, please check my edited post now, I have changed your document root htaccess now, try and let me know then.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happened, no redirects

Comment: @tomasr, could you please make sure your htaccess rule file is enabled? Place a dummy line like `-------` and then hit any url if you get 500 internal error then it means its NOT enabled, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Iif I place this dummy line to any htaccess I will get e500

Comment: @tomasr, ok so you mean you are getting 500 internal error after placing it?

Comment: @tomasr, yes it means its enabled. If you have linux system, could you please try `curl -IL "http://localhost:80/your_url` once and see what comes in it?

Comment: Yes I have linux. Result of cmd is in my question.

Comment: @tomasr, your screen shot shows 200 OK which means link is working fine. Please do let me know where its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233954/discussion-between-tomasr-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @tomasr, sorry I can't join chat room, we could discuss in comments here 

Comment: Ok, but is not organized. What you exactly want to see?
should I give --------- at the end of htaccess and launch that cmd?

Comment: @tomasr, line `-------` was a testing line to test if your htaccess is enabled or not(please remove it now). What I was referring in previous comment is: Link you are giving to curl command is giving 200OK result which means it is working fine. Could you please confirm the same once.

Comment: In screenshot was not use line -----------. Url is working, but is not redirected by rule RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/picture-display/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]

Comment: @tomasr, could you please do let me know path details, Where htaccess is present and where you have path of en/catalog, kindly share it and we will see how it goes.

Comment: I have relative paths both of htaccess in question. en/catalog is not folder, it is roted by Zend Framework. I thought, taht htaccess will take url and change it by some rule. It is not like that?

Comment: @tomasr, could you please do mention it complete paths like: `/root/test/.htaccess`, `/root/test/en/catalog` etc, so that we can think what's going on.

Comment: It is /root/test/public/.htaccess and /root/test/.htaccess. Catalog is routed from controller. Structure of project id complete different from url. This RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/picture-display/(.*)/?$ /en/catalog/europe/finland [L,NC,R=302] works, but rule with params not.

Comment: @tomasr, For your statement `but rule with params not.` you mean you are passing query string to rule `RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/picture-display/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]` if yes then please do let me know here.

Comment: Yes, when I use your rule which mention, it does not redirect, but my rule where miss dynamic part of second part ($1/$2) it works. So just come up with the dynamic part and it should work.

Comment: @tomasr, `So just come up with the dynamic part and it should work.` you mean link could be like: `http://llocalhost:80/test/test/singh/test123`? which you want to redirect to `http://localhost:80/test/test/test123`? I mean by dynamic you mean like this?

Comment: I mean redirect from en/catalog/picture-display/whatever/whatever?whatever to en/catalog/whatever/whatever?whatever. First part (^(en/catalog)/picture-display/(.*)/?$) works well and redirect to static URL (/en/catalog/europe/finland) works, but does not work redirect to dynamic part from your answer ($1/$2).

Comment: I think it could be RewriteRule ^en/catalog/picture-display/(.*)/?$ /en/catalog/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

Comment: @tomasr, Change rule `RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/picture-display/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]` TO `RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/(?:[/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]` once and let me know how it goes, make sure to clear your cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Does not work. It is too generally, I want to remove just one part of url: /picture-display

Comment: @tomasr, change it to `RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]` there was a typo, sorry was taking lunch when I typed it from mobile, this should work IMHO, let me know how it goes.

Comment: It redirects to / (homepage). Maybe it is good and influence it some staff in routing by Zend Framework. I do not know. I found out solution which works like charm. I do not know how can I thank you, but I cannot mark your answer as correct:(.

Answer (score 0):

Please try add rule:

`RewriteRule ^en/catalog/picture-display/(.*)$ en/catalog/$1 [L,NC,R=302]`

before line with `RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way in your site root .htacccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess/?$ - [NC,F]

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(cs/katalog)/obrazkove-zobrazeni/(.*)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(en/catalog)/picture-display/(.*)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, it does not redirect. Can I debug it somehow? Thank you for one step redirect to https www.

Comment: Can you tell your full URL that doesn't redirect. Do make sure that you have no other rule other than this code

Comment: I cannot show full URL, but I found out solution (check my answer). I do not know why it works and your and @RavinderSingh13 does not.

Comment: Your redirect rule is exactly same but with one less capture group only.

Answer (score 0):

Correct htaccess which do what I wanted is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cs/katalog/obrazkove-zobrazeni/(.*)/?$ /cs/katalog/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^en/catalog/picture-display/(.*)/?$ /en/catalog/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess/?$ - [NC,F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

I would like to thank to @RavinderSingh13 and others which tried out help me, but their solutions didn't work unlike mine.

Comment: Good that you have shown your answer to us, to thank all on Stack overflow you could up-vote all helpful answers, cheers and happy learning.